# Show or display items collection or search object in ActiveExplorer

Tags: vba, search, outlook, display

I can capture a collection of items to a variable by Items.Restrict or a Search Object by AdvancedSearch ... how do I display the Items or Search in the ActiveExplorer??

Where objSearch is a Search Object

```
Set objSearch = objOL.AdvancedSearch(strScope, strSearch, True, "PracticeSearch")
```

Or where rtrndItems is an Items Object

```
Set rtrndItems = myItems.Restrict(strSearch)
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these methods are designed to be run programmatically without any UI feedback. The best what you could do is to save the `AdvancedSearch` results into a search folder in Outlook. The [Search.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.search.save) method saves the search results to a `Search` Folder. For example:

```
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean 
 
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search) 
 MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired"
 blnSearchComp = True 
End Sub 
 
Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete() 
 Dim sch As Outlook.Search 
 Dim rsts As Outlook.Results 
 Dim i As Integer 
 blnSearchComp = False 
 Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'" 
 Const strS As String = "Inbox" 
 Set sch = Application.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF)
 While blnSearchComp = False 
   DoEvents
 Wend 
 
 sch.Save("Subject Test") 
 
End Sub
```

To search items in Outlook with any UI feedback involved you need to use the [Explorer.Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.search) method which performs a Microsoft Instant Search on the current folder displayed in the Explorer using the given Query

Here is what MSDN states for the `Search` method:

> The functionality of Explorer.Search is analogous to the Search button in Instant Search. It behaves as if the user has typed the query string in the Instant Search user interface and then clicked Search. When calling Search, the query is run in the user interface, and there is no programmatic mechanism to obtain the search results. For more information on Instant Search, query for "Instant Search" in the Outlook Help.

The `Search` method does not provide a callback to enable the developer to determine when the search is complete.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification.  Can Explorer.Search search by ConversationID or ConversationIndex and the Item.Properties or is it pretty much the same as Instant Search in that it checks subject and body?

Comment: Binary properties are not allowed.